# tar and its key letters: is it a bug or feature?

Tags: linux, command-line, tar

I am wondering to ask the difference of these two commands (i.e. only the order of their options are different):

1. `tar -zxvf foo.tar.gz`
2. `tar -zfxv foo.tar.gz`

The first one ran perfectly but the second one said:

```
tar: You must specify one of the `-Acdtrux' or `--test-label'  options
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
```

And tar with `--test-label` and `-zfxv` said :

```
tar (child): xv: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Then I looked at tar manual and realised that all the example there are using switch `-f` in the end!!

AFAICT there is no need for this restriction, or is there?! because in my view switches should be order free.

Comment: @schily your "correction" to the command lines obscured what command he actually typed. A leading dash changes GNU tar's behavior to use a different argument parser. Using no dash (and thus the traditional argument parser), the second command would have worked.

Comment: The delta printout from the web system told me that you or someone before added the -, so I removed it again to match what the system told me was from the OP. But if you are right with `gtar option parsing`, you discovered another reason for not using gtar.

Comment: ``-f`` expects the filename to follow. In your second version, you specified ``-fxv``, which - for tar - means that the filename is "xv".

Comment: Obligatory [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/1168/).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looking at your error message, it is obvious that you did not use `tar` but rather `gtar`.

In general this may help to understand things:

- `tar` normally always needs a file argument. If it is missing, it will read/write from/to the system's default real tape device. `star` changed this in 1982 to use stdin/stdout by default and some other tar implementations (e.g. gtar) followed this example recently.
- `tar` does not implement the leading `-` for options that are called `key letters` in the case of the tar command. Some implementations later added `-` as a no-op key letter for users' convenience but you cannot rely on this.
- The way `tar` parses its arguments (in particular the archive file argument) is highly risky. I have seen many tar archives that destroyed one of the files that should be in the archive because the related file argument was taken as tar archive file. `star` for this reason (if called natively as `star`) does not allow "f" to be concatenated with other options. If `star` is called `tar` it implements command line compatibility with `tar`, but still handles the argument for the "f" key letter differently: the argument is only permitted if it refers to a real device file or when (in write mode) the file does not yet exist.

I recommend avoiding the risky original tar command line and rather using the modern safer command line syntax you get with `star`.

Because of the problematic command line syntax of `tar`, there were the so called `tar wars` in the early 1990s. As a result, the program `pax` (Latin for "peace" in the tar wars) was created and standardized. `pax` however did not gain popularity as its syntax is less risky but also less intuitive than the tar syntax. Another problem may be that `gpax` is more or less unmaintained.

Comment: The tar wars are over. guntar won.

Comment: If you were right, why do all tar implementations copy features from `star`?

Comment: BTW: the tar wars have been a battle between `tar` and `cpio`.

Comment: Note that `star -c -f"$file" files` works but only as long as `$file` is not `ind`, so even with the `-x` style of option, with `star`, it's better to separate the option from the argument (and to separate each single letter option in case their combination may form a long option). GNU or BSD tar don't have those problems as long options are introduced with a double-dash there.

Comment: If you follow the man page and use f=filename or if you follow the POSIX Utility Argument Syntax and place a space between the option letter and the option argument, you do not suffer from this problem. BTW: Long options have been invented by UNOS (the first UNIX clone) in 1980 and implemented with a single -. The form `-long` violates one POSIX argument syntax rule but the form `--long` violates two POSIX rules.

Comment: This is quite a long, interesting, and informed answer, despite the fact that it does not ever address the actual problem.

Comment: --long doesn't violate POSIX because POSIX doesn't specify any long option, nor the `-` short option in any of the utilities. POSIX doesn't specify `tar` any more (if it ever did, it's not in the SUS since v3) `-long` would violate POSIX commands that support `-l <arg>` or `-l -o -n -g` (like `ls`). It even _violates_ in a way your own `star` because `-find` conflicts with `-f'ind'`

Comment: OK, so it seems `star`'s `-f"$file"` is also (in addition to `ind`) a problem with file names starting with `=`. So one needs to write it either `-f="$file"` or `-f "$file"`. I'm not sure I would call your star option parsing _safer_ or _modern_.

Comment: Please read the POSIX Utility Syntax guidelines for more information on what POSIX thinks about options. Regarding the quality of my option parser: it is much better than the gnu parser. After converting mkisofs from GNU getopt_long() to getargs(), all problems with the option definitions and the way getopt_long() parses options have been fixed. To understand this, please read the POSIX utility guidelines: it says that if a man page says -f arg, you are not allowed to assume that -farg works as well. getargs() on the other side can be told that there must be a space between option and argument

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas - BTW: thank you four your hint, I'll change `star` to use "f& " instead of "f&" for getargs() to enforce a space or "=" after  -f to avoid the option problem you discovered. The funny thing is that this is exactly in the getargs() comment already since 2006 but I did not add this to star.c. Note that POSIX mentions that the man page is important whether -farg or -f arg is the right way to go.

Comment: Older versions of the spec _allowed_ implementations (of utilities) to support `-o<arg>` in addition to `-o <arg>`. The [latest version](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_01) _requires_ them to also support `-o<arg>` in addition to `-o <arg>`. It still requires an application (like a script using those utilities) to use the `-o <arg>`. That's a transition period for the remaining few traditional utilities that still don't support the condensed form like some `sh -oxtrace` or `awk -vvar=value`.

Comment: `-long` style long options are incompatible with condensed `-xyz` short options or `-xarg`. That's why X11 style long options require short options to be separate (`-x -y`,  not `-xy`) and option arguments to be on separate arguments (`xterm -n foo`, not `xterm -nfoo`). And that's why there's an extra dash in GNU long options, to remove the possible confusion with short options, and why GNU-style long options are a better design. You can have `-foo` coexist with `-x -y -xy` only if you're very careful to avoid the overlaps.

Comment: You missread the POSIX guidelines. 6: option and option argument should be in separate arguments, 7: option arguments should not be optional. A conforming application only needs to accept option and argument argument in a single argument if that option is documented to have an optional argument. BTW: long options with a single - have a 35 year history and work perfectly as long as long options are first tried to match and only later, the possibility of combined single char options is checked.

Comment: "Less intuitive than the tar syntax"? [You can do that?](https://xkcd.com/1168/)

Comment: @schily The problem is if the user _intends_ combined single character _standard_ options (and the standard already allows them to be combined, unlike for X11 apps), but what they type gets interpreted as a long _extended_ option. You can get away with it by making sure every long option includes at least one character that doesn't appear in any short option - which is effectively what `--long` actually does. You can't demand the user to type `-glno` when the standard requires `-long` to work with the same meaning.

Answer (score 56):

The order of switches is free, but `-f` has a mandatory argument which is the file that `tar` will read/write.

You could do

```
tar -zf foo.tar.gz -xv
```

and that will work, and has your requirement of a non-specific order of switches.

This is how all commands that have options that have arguments work.

Comment: Tar does not work like other commands as it uses a different much older command line parser - the same that is used in the "ar" command and the old (pre-POSIX) "ps" command.

Comment: Thank you for this, the selected answer, while thorough, did not really allow me to see what specifically the problem was. In retrospect, it seems obvious from the error message stating tar was trying to read the file 'xv'

Comment: I believe you can also declare it as `-f=./myfile`, that is to say, f takes a value, it isn't a flag, its an input.

Answer (score 14):

Traditionally, tar's options *are* more or less "order-free" (the order of the `f` and `b` options do matter if both are specified). Using a leading dash, however, causes GNU tar to parse the options in a way considered more consistent with other commands, where specifying an option that requires an argument (such as the filename for `f`) will immediately consume the rest of the "word", if any, as the argument (traditionally, tar uses the *next* word as the filename / block size when `f` or `b` is specified). In your case, it took "xv" as the filename.

This behavior cannot be relied on for portability, though. For maximum portability, you should avoid using a dash, always put `f` last, and always put a space between `f` and the filename. This is, though, a simplification that breaks down if you need the `b` option or in general any option (such as `C`) other than `f` that requires an argument.

This is documented in the [Tar Manual section "The Three Option Styles"](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/tar_21.html). Some other implementations (e.g. FreeBSD) refer to the old style options as a "bundled option word". And of course, some implementations may *only* support this type of option, and may or may not ignore a dash if included. This is the only form of invocation specified in the Single Unix Specification and therefore guaranteed to work on almost all systems.

Comment: Note that some implementations support other options with arguments (like `C` in BSD or GNU tar. schily tar supports it as -C but not as C, all support it as -C).

Answer (score 0):

In tar, the **-** in the switches has been deprecated many years ago and is no longer necessary.  Tar actually used to tell you that but no longer does.

```
ie:
tar zxvf foo.tar.gz
tar zfxv foo.tar.gz

Both of these work fine without the -.
```